# Textview animation is cropped by image view

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation, textview

I have textview that has scale down animation. When it is big, it is being cropped/cut by the image view below it. As it is shrinking the full text is appearing untill it takes its normal size.

How can I have the text be on top of the image view even during animation?

Thank you

Comment: cropped/cut... I think it is hiding behind the ImageView. Can you copy your xml layout file here?

Comment: I am not sure why this question is put on hold. It is very valid. During animation of a view, how can I make sure that the view is is not hidden/cut or cropped?

Comment: @vinaykumar, I will post the xml when I come back althought I don't see the point of it as it is just relative layout that says put the textview above the imageview. But when textview is scaling during animation and overlap happens and the image view is on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relative layout and put textview above your image view so that they don't overlap

Comment: I did, but when animating the text view expands the imageview does not move it just overlaps and sit on top

Comment: Try to change the order of textview and imageview. i.e. just write imageview before textview that will bring textview in front. Or try using vertical linearlayout and put textview, imageview in it.

Comment: The order fixed it :)